# Exchange 2003 / 2010 Public Folder Restore or Sync Tool needed

Tags: exchange-2003, exchange-2010, restore, public-folders, database-restore

What tools exist to restore public folder data?

If nothing will assist in (exmerging) PF data, what tools exist to sync data between backup sets?... between forests?

It seems that pfdavadmin was used to change the replicas and we now have a horribly corrupt Exchange 2010 /03 PF environment.  The long and short of it is that we used to have a fully replicated (6 copies each ) environment and now only 2 exist.

I'm pulling an all nighter here, so please bare with my phrasing.  Feel free to ask for more information....

Comment: Sorry to hear you are having a rough night. You don't have any backup for your Exchange environment? I would consider deleting them all and restoring if you have something like Backup Exec and the Exchange agent. In the future, pfdavadmin is not supported for Exchange 2010 per http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=635be792-d8ad-49e3-ada4-e2422c0ab424&displaylang=en As a rule of thumb, you always manage from the latest version of Exchange. Last suggestion is that you may want to bite the bullet and call Microsoft for $260 if it gets much worse, or before it gets worse.

Comment: I have to agree with kcotreau, without proper backups in place you could really paint yourself into a corner.  If it's worth pulling an allnighter, it's probably worth a call to the vendor.

Comment: How did you make out, and what did you do to resolve it?

Comment: Still on with MSFT premier support - Sev A.  Slept 3 hours.  Issue is that all folders (system and public) are not available to many usrs in many sites.  Still triaging.

Comment: Good luck. If you have been up all night with support, imagine without it.

Comment: something for the future: Public folder replication to a secondary public folder (i.e not a replicated one). Take a look at the tools from CodeTwo - it depends on what you have in your PF's but they should work well.